# In the LXX of 2 Samuel 5:18, what is the meaning of the word «τιτάνων»?

Tags: greek, septuagint, 2-samuel

In 2 Sam. 5:18, the Hebrew text states,

> <sup>יח</sup> וּפְלִשְׁתִּים בָּאוּ וַיִּנָּטְשׁוּ בְּעֵמֶק רְפָאִים

which is translated into the Greek Septuagint as,

> <sup>ΙΗʹ</sup> καὶ οἱ ἀλλόφυλοι παραγίνονται καὶ συνέπεσαν εἰς τὴν κοιλάδα τῶν **τιτάνων** <sup>Rahlfs</sup>

The Greek word «τιτάνων» seemed peculiar. Elsewhere, the Hebrew word רְפָאִים (*rephaʾim*) was transliterated (rather than translated) in the LXX as Ραφαϊν.<sup>1</sup>

1. To what does the Greek word «τιτάνων» refer to (i.e., its meaning)?
2. Are there any textual variants among the manuscripts of the LXX for this particular verse?

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> cp. Deu. 2:11

Comment: Interestingly, the parallel in 2 Chr 14:9 has κοιλὰς τῶν **γιγάντων** (cf. Gen 14:5, Josh 13:12, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand Swete's apparatus correctly, there is no difference between the Alexandrinus and Vaticanus Codices.

The only thing I notice here is that the word is used in a place name (i.e. the "Valley of the Titans/Giants").  I had noticed that place names in the Septuagint always seem to be literally translated into their Greek meanings, even if the place is well known by some Hebrew proper name.  For example,

> *And he called the name of the place Massah, and Meribah, because of the chiding of the children of Israel, and because they tempted the
>   LORD, saying, Is the LORD among us, or not?* (Exodus 17:7, KJV)

reads, in the Septuagint,

> *And he called the name of that place, Temptation, and Reviling* [Πειρασμὸς καὶ Λοιδόρησις]*, because of the reviling of the children
>   of Israel, and because they tempted the Lord, saying, Is the Lord
>   among us or not?* (Brenton LXX)